# hotspots map using kernel density estimation in R

Tags: r, mapping, kernel-density

I have x,y coordinates of car accidents within a city. I would like to create hotspots map using kernel density estimation in R. anyone can help with the code ?

Comment: If you want anybody to really help you with this please [provide a reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5963269/how-to-make-a-great-r-reproducible-example). For example update your question with the code you have tried with the geyser data from MASS, so we can see what the error is.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The `spatstat` package makes this easy. Since I don't know what your data looks like, I'll start by creating some demo data.

```
x <- rnorm(327)
y <- runif(327)
```

Now convert the data into a geospatial format using the `ppp()` function from `spatstat`.

```
library(spatstat)
dta <- ppp(x, y, window = owin(c(-5, 5), c(-5, 5)))
```

Finally, compute the density and then plot the result.

```
# Compute the density function
dta <- density(dta)

# Plot the density
plot(dta, main = "Density plot of sample dataset")
```

[image]

Comment: Thank u very much. I am trying to use a different data which has few hotspots and not only one as in your example but i always get 1 hotspot. I tried "geyser" data from MASS library which has 3 hotspots. why it doesnt work?